# Stdout to memory python

Tags: vlc

I wanted to stream the raspivid using VLC. So I followed the below link

```
raspivid -o - -t 9999999 -w 1280 -h 1024 -b 500000 -fps 20|cvlc -vvv stream:///dev/stdin --sout '#rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8080/}' :demux=h264
```

Now I wanted to record the streamed result in vlc with

```
cvlc -vvv stream:///rtsp://0.0.0.0:8554/}'  --sout=file/ps:record.mpg
```

Am I doing it right? Alternative approach/methods appreciated.

Comment: Question: Streaming with vlc rtsp and capturing with vlc

Comment: For capturing (receiving end), I think you should use 127.0.0.1 instead of 0.0.0.0

Comment: Thanks I've update 0.0.0.0 to 127.0.0.1. Is it possible to stop os.system('cvlc -vvv stream:///rtsp://0.0.0.0:8554/}'  --sout=file/ps:record.mpg'') for each one hour and restart it again in python with different file name[timestamp prefered- I've done this]?